# porting wxwidgets opengl application to not library dependent application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, mfc, wxwidgets

I want to port wxwidgets opengl application that will be not library dependent.I want at least  that it can be compiled without additonal libraries. I am thinking to port it to MFC or maybe WIN32.What is the most easiest?Maybe you have  some other suggestion?

Comment: You do realize, that MFC is just another library and works much like wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC is by far the easiest. It's also the only realistic option if you don't want to use libraries that aren't installed with Visual Studio.

Comment: OK but that would add a .Net dependency, not to mention that Winforms is deprecated. It's not really a 'C++' application any more after that, at best a 'C++ for the CLR' application.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize, that MFC is just another library and works much like wxWidgets. The only difference is, that MFC ships with Visual C++. However if you were to compile with GCC (MinGW), then you'd have to obtain MFC somehow.

Also the whole boilerplate code for event handling and the like is rather prone to write. I say: Stick with wxWidgets, it's cross plattform, well supported and if you're scared by installing and using libraries, then you should not do programming.

Comment: @Roel: Admittingly, bad example. But I'm not so sure about this actually. At least VC++5 shipped with the full MFC source code so in theory one could port it to GCC, cleansing all compiler dependencies beforehand of course. However there's the Intel compiler, and MFC works with that one.

Comment: Yes, if one were to modify the code so that it would work, but by that reasoning any library is 'portable'. IIRC there are serious problems; for example the use of thunking to associate window handles with objects using compiler details that only hold for MSVC. I'm not sure about the Intel compiler or if it actually works with MFC - from a cursory look I can't find a page where Intel claims it does, for example.

Comment: As a matter of fact VS Pro and better ship with the entire source code of MFC. This is done to facilitate debugging your MFC application. I don't know about the legal ramifications, but it should be technical possible to compile MFC with gcc on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Although one answer is already checked, taking the question the way it was worded, the answer is wrong. MFC is just an other dependency, although shipped with Visual Studio. You still need to ensure that the correct version is installed on the users system. The only real way to solve this problem is to go Win32 with WGL. Then you depend on nothing but OS libraries. (You probably still need to install the vcredist package though...)